# Making a keyboard in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I made a keyboard using jetpack compose for tv app:

```
      when (keyboardType) {
       KeyboardType.EnglishCharacters -> EnglishCharacters(
           switchToArabicCharacters = keyboardAction::switchToArabicCharacters,
           switchToEnglishSymbols = keyboardAction::switchToEnglishSymbols,
           onCharacterClicked = keyboardAction::onCharacterSelected,
           onDeleteClicked = keyboardAction::delete,
           onClearClicked = keyboardAction::clear,
           onForwardClicked = keyboardAction::moveCursorForward,
           onSpaceClicked = keyboardAction::space,
           onBackwardClicked = keyboardAction::moveCursorBackward
       )

       KeyboardType.EnglishSymbols -> EnglishSymbols(
           switchToEnglishCharacters = keyboardAction::switchToEnglishCharacters,
           onCharacterClicked = keyboardAction::onCharacterSelected,
           onForwardClicked = keyboardAction::moveCursorForward,
           onBackwardClicked = keyboardAction::moveCursorBackward,
           onClearClicked = keyboardAction::clear,
           onDeleteClicked = keyboardAction::delete,
           onSpaceClicked = keyboardAction::space
       )

       KeyboardType.ArabicCharacters -> ArabicCharacters(
           switchToArabicSymbols = keyboardAction::switchToArabicSymbols,
           switchLanguage = keyboardAction::switchToEnglishCharacters,
           onCharacterClicked = keyboardAction::onCharacterSelected,
           onDeleteClicked = keyboardAction::delete,
           onClearClicked = keyboardAction::clear,
           onForwardClicked = keyboardAction::moveCursorForward,
           onBackwardClicked = keyboardAction::moveCursorBackward,
           onSpaceClicked = keyboardAction::space
       )
```

and inside each function I define a variable for the characetrs:

```
    val firstRow = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i")
val secondRow = listOf("j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r")
val thirdRow = listOf("s", "t", "u", "v", "u", "x", "y", "z")
```

and for the special cases I just hardcode them:

```
        DeleteKey {
        onDeleteClicked()
    }

    ClearKey {
        onClearClicked()
    }
```

However, I want to change it to be just one function, that gets a list of keys, considiring that there are different types of keys (characters space delete switch language).

Is there any suggestion of how that could be done?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be specific to Compose at all. IIUC you want to have both "letter key" objects and "special key" objects in the same list, so they must share a base class or interface. You could use a sealed class/interface with one subclass for letter keys and one for each special key. Or you could use an enum; in Kotlin, enum members can override functions of the enum.

```
interface KeyboardActionReceiver { // you may be able to use the `TextField` or w/e directly instead of using a wrapper, this is just to show which functions I've used below
    fun addChar(c: Char)
    fun clear()
}

enum class Key {
    A, B, C,
    Clear {
        override fun KeyboardActionReceiver.keydown(): Unit
            = this.clear()
    };

    open fun KeyboardActionReceiver.keydown(): Unit
        = this.addChar(this@Key.name[0].lowercaseChar()) // please don't actually use `name`
}

// ...
val l = listOf(Key.A, Key.Clear)
l.forEach { Key(it, onKeyDown = it::keydown) } // Compose stuff goes here
```